Client Certificate to access specific APIs for application hosted on AWS
I have an AWS application with two types of APIs: functional and business. I'm using a load balancer to route traffic to both APIs through a listener on HTTPS:443 with rules for accessing both APIs.
The issue I'm facing is that the business APIs require a client certificate that is sent with the user request, and I'm unable to find a solution for how to implement this.
Solution tried:

Activate mTLS on HTTPS:443 listener, but then the client certifcate is implemented on both the APIs.
Created another HTTPS listener on port 8443, and created a rule in HTTPS:443 listener to redirect the request to 8443 for business APIs. But this doesn't support POST and PUT as request methods.

I am expecting if someone have another idea to tackle this problem.
Thanks in advance.
